# 3D editor with a ability to draw 2D vector graphics on a surface?

Tags: 3d, vector-graphics

Suppose I drew a cube in Blender. I can apply a material on it's surface which is in fact 2D raster graphics.

But I want vector graphics, not raster.

So, are there any 3D editors, which allows to draw 2D vector graphics on a surface of 2D objects? Not only flat surface, i.e. I want to be able to draw of the surface of a sphere too.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is your question:

> Suppose you have a 3d cube in the scene, you can apply a raster image
> texture on it and start painting. But you prefer vector shapes over brush
> strokes.

Well, for your knowledge *.svg* is a common format for vector graphics. But unfortunately, blender can only import *svg*s as meshes, not as textures.

But if its 'vector shapes' OR the almighty 'pen tool' you want to use, I'd suggest you try:

1. UV mapping HD textures exported from a vector program. ([example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NIUmEUDhjdOUOnFiiKJdMK5K_LxMse_e/view))
2. Using the gorgeous quick edit method after specifying the file path to your favourite graphics program.([example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lLnSE9OxwtY1l-xHVCGisvjOVv9Uemgn/view?usp=sharing))